# I want to specify a color in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want to use plotly to specify the color.
However, with the current code, using `marker=dict(color=colors)` will naturally result in an error.
How can I specify the type and also the color at the same time?

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(
    df,
    x=x_axis,
    y=y_axis,
    color="species",
)
fig.show()
```

As an image, I want to specify something like this. `color` is a list, and it contains the same kind of data as `species`.

```py
import seaborn as sns

def get_colorpalette(colorpalette, file_number):
    palette = sns.color_palette(
        colorpalette, file_number)
    rgb = ['rgb({},{},{},{})'.format(*[x*256 for x in rgb],1)
           for rgb in palette]
    return rgb

colors = get_colorpalette('hls', graphNumber)

fig = px.scatter(
    df,
    x=x_axis,
    y=y_axis,
    color="species",
    marker=dict(color=colors)
)
fig.show()
```

postscript
I have prepared `color` in RGB, but it would be nice if I could specify the color in RGB in plotly.

The following is an example of how to specify a color in plotly.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

import plotly.graph_objs as go 
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly

def get_colorpalette(colorpalette, n_colors):
    palette = sns.color_palette(
        colorpalette, n_colors)
    rgb = ['rgb({},{},{})'.format(*[x*256 for x in rgb])
           for rgb in palette]
    return rgb

n_legends = 12
x = np.arange(0, 1, .01)
y = np.random.rand(n_legends, 100) + \
  np.arange(n_legends).reshape(-1, 1)

colors = get_colorpalette('hls', n_legends)
data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y[i], name='凡例 {:02d}'.format(i),
        marker={'color':colors[i]})
    for i in range(n_legends)]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: `NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-637885ba71a4> in <module>
----> 1 colors = get_colorpalette('hls', graphNumber*2)
      2 import plotly.express as px
      3 import plotly.graph_objects as go
      4 
      5 # fig = go.Figure(

NameError: name 'get_colorpalette' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary color settings can be made with the following settings See this page for details. The following code was taken from the sample in the official reference.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x="sepal_width",
                 y="sepal_length",
                 color="species",
                 size='petal_length',
                 hover_data=['petal_width'],
                 color_discrete_sequence=["blue", "goldenrod", "magenta"])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer. GANBATTE!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, I didn't have enough information about `color`, so I supplemented it.
I would be grateful if it could be specified in RGB.

Comment: Where color is specified, color name, hexadecimal format, and rgb() are also possible. So the following code is also valid. `color_discrete_sequence=["rgb(40, 40, 40)", "rgb(80, 80, 80)", "rgb(120, 120, 120)"]`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Plotly Express will use the color sequence from the active template's layout. colorway attribute, and the default active template is plotly which uses the plotly color sequence. You can choose any of the following built-in qualitative color sequences from the px. colors.